# Datatables: Custom types

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

I am having some problems creating custom types for my data table, using jquery.datatables.js.

My table initialization looks like this:

```
    drawTable['#<?= $tab ?>'] = function() {
                    $('#sites_<?= $tab ?>').dataTable({
                    'iDisplayLength' : 25,
                    'aaSorting': [[5, 'desc']],
                    'aLengthMenu': [[25, 50, 100, -1], [25, 50, 100, 'All']],
                    'aoColumns' : [
                        {'sType' : 'formatted-num'},
                        null,
                        null,
                        null,
                        {'sType' : 'formatted-num'},
                        {'sType' : 'formatted-num'},
                        {'sType' : 'formatted-num'},
                        {'sType' : 'formatted-num'},
                        {'sType' : 'formatted-num'},
                        {'sType' : 'formatted-num'}
                    ]
                })
};
```

And then:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                drawTable['#<?= $tab ?>']();
                drawnTable['#<?= $tab ?>'] = true;
            });
```

The $tab is to select some values from server.

That works well for the custom types, but I need to create my own type. How do I do so? I have been reading some of the examples here: http://www.datatables.net/plug-ins/type-detection but all of them seem to be done for tables started with only `$(document).ready(function() {
                $('#example').dataTable();
            } );`

Not really sure how to implement at least one of those to one of my columns, if I could at least do that I would just write my own function. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how it is done:

```
    jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['num-html-asc']  = function(a,b) {
    a = ;//changes to remove html signs
    b = ;//same as above
    return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ?  1 : 0));
};

jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['num-html-desc'] = function(a,b) {
    a = ;//changes to remove html signs
    b = ;//same as above
    return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ?  -1 : 0));
};
```

Include that function after including datatables.js, but before initializing it. Then in the column that needs to use that

```
{'sType' : 'num-html'},
```

That's all.